# ELASTICSEARCH - Filter_path query with backslash

Tags: elasticsearch

I trying to get the value in fields with backslash through filter_path, but It doesn't return nothing.

```
GET mike/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source.data.add.ces.info
    {
      "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
          {
            "_source" : {
              "data" : [
                {
                  "add" : [
                    {
                      "ces" : [
                        {
                          "info" : "{\"@color\": \"red\",\"state\": 
                          {\"@state\": \"open\", \"@reason\": \"null\"}}"
                        }

GET mike/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source.data.add.ces.info.@color
{}
```

How can I access the information with backslash and show it on my screen?

Comment: It seems that the content of `info` is a stringified JSON... if that's the case you cannot fetch the color field. You need to parse the value at indexing time

Comment: Should I define a mapping with field @color?